# Change the data for the chart

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I've used this code: [Leaflet and Popup with D3](http://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/11602fac1ea66c2a6d7f78067b2deddb) for my Leaflet project.

The problem is, I don't understand how I can change the data. I don't need months in the chart but something else. Where in the code can I change this?

Answer (score 2):

When you click, you call the function `chart`. Within this function you get the data from clicked feature e.g

```js
  var feature = d.feature;
  var data = feature.properties.data;
```

Then you set the div to prepare height and width for the chart and instanciate a svg element

The code with `var x = ...` helps to calculate the width of each bar in the diagram by stating you need to divide total width by 12.

The `var xAxis = ...` prepares to set label for months reusing `x` variable.

The `g.append("g") ...` part states you want to add the label to the DOM (as SVG)

You draw the bar with the following reusing data from the feature you clicked

```
var rects = g.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    ...
```

So `data` value when you click on first feature will be `[10,12,16,20,25,30,30,29,13,10,7,6]` and you will resue it to display the 12 bars for months

So the solution is not about changing only the data but also the label and the scale `x` depending of the data you will use.

I've made a correction due to your comment. You can see the changes at https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/db5ab90f2270dc31c98d192d31656e24/revisions and the demo at http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/db5ab90f2270dc31c98d192d31656e24

Comment: hello thank you for letting me understand the code! I'm doing a school project and what I want to display in the chart are votes, my problem is know that I don't know how I will get 6 electoral parties now In the same line as the months rn. Do. I need to work with Strings?

Comment: Made a demo, see edited answer

Comment: thank you so much! this helped a lot!!

Comment: I'm sorry for asking again, I've been looking on google for a long for a real answer, but there is a solution to get each variable a different color in the chart?

Comment: There is and it's quite common. Googling will not be enough to get the exact recipe. You need to understand how to code with D3 (at least to know what you do not just pass the grade). I've made change to the sample to deal with colors. It's quite "hackkish" (the initial data structure was not intended for this and I've made patches instead of refactoring code...)

Comment: Your question, as it was formulated, was more than answered by @ThomassG77. It would seem appropriate to accept it. If you have any additional questions you should post them as separate questions.